# Identify Started Service App by Powershell

Tags: powershell, service-application, service-applications

I am using the following Powershell script in hopes of identifying Started service applications by server.

Spot checking the results shows something unexpected.  For instance, I know Lotus Notes Connector is Stopped on all servers in my farm but the script returns it.

What other additional properties must I test for to be sure I am seeing the exact same results as shown in Central Admin "Manage Services on Servers" page?

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$ReportInfo = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)


$servers = (get-spfarm).servers
foreach ($server in $servers)
{


    foreach($service in $server.serviceinstances)
    {
        if($service.TypeName -eq "Lotus Notes Connector"){
            Write-Host stop;
        }

        if ($service.status = "Online")
        {
            Write-Host "Server" $server.Name "`tService: " $service.TypeName;

            $servicInfo = @{}
            $servicInfo.Server = $service.Server.Name;
            $servicInfo.Service = $service.TypeName;

            $ReportInfo.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $servicInfo))>$null;
        }
    }
}

Write-Host "Exporting CSV"

$ReportInfo | Export-Csv  "Services.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter '|'
```

Comment: Pls change <br/>
*if ($service.status = "Online")* <br/>
by <br/>
*if ($service.status -eq "Online")* <br/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong with simply using

`Get-SPServiceInstance | select typename, status, server | Export-Csv test.csv`

to get the data?

Comment: Nothing.  Looks great.  Thanks for simplifying for us.

Answer (score 0):

When using PowerShell to get the service instances, they all seem to come back online, as you describe.  However, if we do it in a C# method, it comes back correctly.  Here is what I did to make them come back correctly:

```
$Assem = ( 
    "Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
    ) 

$Source = @" 
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration; 
using Microsoft.SharePoint; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System; 

namespace ReportingStuff 
{ 
    public static class Servers  
    { 
        public static List<SPServiceInstance> GetInstances() 
        { 
            List<SPServiceInstance> items = new List<SPServiceInstance>();

            foreach (SPServer server in SPFarm.Local.Servers)
            {
                foreach (SPServiceInstance instance in server.ServiceInstances)
                {
                    if ((!instance.SystemService && !(instance.GetType().FullName.Contains("SPAdministrationServiceInstance"))) && (!(instance is SPTimerServiceInstance) && (server.ServiceInstances.GetValue<SPTimerServiceInstance>() != null)))
                        items.Add(instance);
                }
            }

            return items;
        } 
    } 
} 
"@ 

Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp  

$output = [ReportingStuff.Servers]::GetInstances()
Write-Output $output
```

You can use the method to get your collection of instances and then do your filtering, outputting, etc.

Comment: That is some crazy powershell code.  Never seen that before.  Thanks I'll try it.

Comment: This is not coming back correctly either.  Lotus Notes Connector            Online   c6a52514-1689-4d38-a235-62b96e9e577a

Comment: Do all of the services show online with that script?

Comment: I ran it again and and all Lotus Notes Connectors are listed as Disabled.  Cant explain why previous cut/paste showed Online but I am going to mark this a solved for now.  Thanks

Lotus Notes Connector Disabled c6a52514-1689-4d38-a235-62b96e9e577a
Lotus Notes Connector Disabled 2b35170b-f238-4bbd-a67c-96576f2ad4b1
Lotus Notes Connector Disabled c5565fab-8eee-4c02-a666-361175268cca
Lotus Notes Connector Disabled b587822e-9ece-444b-86c0-99beb6606f57
Lotus Notes Connector Disabled ad73f115-30ec-49b3-8bd0-43071c3da4e1